# Deterministically expand the number of public/private keys

Tags: algorithm, blockchain, ethereum, cryptocurrency

I need to deterministically extend public and private keys (ethereum). How can I do this, who can suggest an algorithm?

Comment: Expand from what? One private key can generate one public key. _(I'm purposely ignoring hash collisions, as this doesn't seem like a question about collisions.)_ So if you have N private keys, you can use them to generate exactly N public keys... Can you elaborate on the use case, inputs that you have and expected outputs?

Comment: @PetrHejda I suppose that the question is about retrieving private keys from the seed phrase. But the response to that is straightforward - to change the derivation path.

Comment: @PetrHejda, I saw about it in this article: https://blog.1inch.io/a-vulnerability-disclosed-in-profanity-an-ethereum-vanity-address-tool-68ed7455fc8c and I wondered what it means to extend the public key in a deterministic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post linked in the question comments mentions risks related to generating vanity addresses from a deterministic source of randomness.

A vanity address is an address that contains a predefined set of bytes, for example starts with 4 zeros. These vanity tools use a loop to generate a random private key, its corresponding address, and validate if the address matches the criteria. If the address doesn't match the criteria, it runs another iteration of the loop.

Simplified example, looking for address starting with `0x1`

1. Generate private key `0x123`, its corresponding address is `0x456`. Doesn't match the criteria, trying again.
2. Generate private key `0xd3f`, its corresponding address is `0xb7c`. Doesn't match the criteria, trying again.
3. Generate private key `0x837`, its corresponding address ix `0x154`. Success.

Some of these vanity tools generate private keys by using a deterministic seed generating algorithm, so it is possible (with some brute force guessing) to recreate the specific private keys that were used and reclaim access to these addresses.

---

A solution that is considered safe is to let each user generate their own pseudo-random seed. A great example is tracking the movements of their mouse cursor as you can see on [this page](https://www.bitaddress.org/).

Or generally, accept the seed from multiple sources - e.g. `/dev/random` from multiple physical machines.

---

Edit: Generating multiple addresses from an xpub:

```
const HDNode = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromExtendedKey("xpub661MyMwAqRbcGXSTUwJkaLaZFy6xdVk8XuRuSEFThgCPFEjrh9WAyREtMhuHA7XMMDXXTm41GfjKDCsLJ2fGfVp1ACyuDKwsShNcGWenHET");
const address0 = HDNode.derivePath("0").address;
const address1 = HDNode.derivePath("1").address;
```

Comment: The article states:
1. Get a public key from a vanity address (recover from the transaction signature).
2. Expand it deterministically to 2 mln public keys.
3. Repeatedly decrement them until they reach the seed public key.
I don't understand the second point, what does it mean, how do I do this?

Comment: @Galaxy773 The second point talks about **xpub**, an "extended public key". One xpub (derived from an extended private key, e.g. from a mnemonic phrase) can be derived into multiple public keys using derivation path. I updated the answer with a code example.

Comment: Sorry to pry, but could you explain the third point as well?